# How to make different button open different activities?

Tags: android

I am working on my first app that needs a few windows. I made six buttons but al of them open the same activity. How to fix that? Sorry for the messy code I am just beginning. Also, a few tips on how to make my code tidier would also help.
This is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button button1 = findViewById(R.id.button1);
        Button button2 = findViewById(R.id.button2);
        Button button3 = findViewById(R.id.button3);
        Button button4 = findViewById(R.id.button4);
        Button button5 = findViewById(R.id.button5);
        Button button6 = findViewById(R.id.button6);

        button1.setOnClickListener(this);
        button2.setOnClickListener(this);
        button3.setOnClickListener(this);
        button4.setOnClickListener(this);
        button5.setOnClickListener(this);
        button6.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.button1:
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, objektas1.class);
            startActivity(intent1);
            break;
        case R.id.button2:
            Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, objektas2.class);
            startActivity(intent2);
            break;
        case R.id.button3:
            Intent intent3 = new Intent(this, objektas3.class);
            startActivity(intent3);
            break;
        case R.id.button4:
            Intent intent4 = new Intent(this, objektas4.class);
            startActivity(intent4);
            break;
        case R.id.button5:
            Intent intent5 = new Intent(this, objektas5.class);
            startActivity(intent5);
            break;
        case R.id.button6:
            Intent intent6 = new Intent(this, objektas6.class);
            startActivity(intent6);
            break;
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: For write Clean code you should lear informations like this https://refactoring.guru/

Comment: Everything seems to be in order in your code. You may be mistaken in thinking that your code is incorrect. But in fact your windows are the same!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code seems to be ok, I just copy your code and made some changes

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button button1 = findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Button button2 = findViewById(R.id.button2);
    Button button3 = findViewById(R.id.button3);

    button1.setOnClickListener(this);
    button2.setOnClickListener(this);
    button3.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.button1:
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, FirstActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent1);
            break;
        case R.id.button2:
            Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent2);
            break;
        case R.id.button3:
            Intent intent3 = new Intent(this, ThirdActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent3);
            break;
    }
}
}
```

Just to be sure see the next images

[image]

check the structure of your project, you should have something very similar but with 7 activities (MainActivity + objektas1...objektas6).

Remember every time you create a new activity the layout is empty so try to add a TextView or something similar to see the difference.

And one last advice try to use names like **ObjektasActivity** instead of **objektas1**

Comment: Thanks for the help but I found my mistake, it was in layout. It happened because iI was copy-pasting all the contents of the layouts.